# How to resize videogular2 component in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, videogular

I had a HTML component from videogular2 for a videoplayer:

```
<vg-player>
<vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play>
<vg-buffering></vg-buffering>

<vg-scrub-bar>
    <vg-scrub-bar-current-time></vg-scrub-bar-current-time>
    <vg-scrub-bar-buffering-time></vg-scrub-bar-buffering-time>
</vg-scrub-bar>

<vg-controls>
    <vg-play-pause></vg-play-pause>
    <vg-playback-button></vg-playback-button>

    <vg-time-display vgProperty="current" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>

    <vg-scrub-bar style="pointer-events: none;"></vg-scrub-bar>

    <vg-time-display vgProperty="left" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>
    <vg-time-display vgProperty="total" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>

    <vg-track-selector></vg-track-selector>
    <vg-mute></vg-mute>
    <vg-volume></vg-volume>

    <vg-fullscreen></vg-fullscreen>
</vg-controls>

<video [vgMedia]="media" #media id="singleVideo" preload="auto" crossorigin>
    <source src="http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.mp4">
</video>
```

How can I resize this component? It fit to all page width. I've already tried add vg-width and vg-height property in the vg-player tag but it does not work.
Thanks! :)

Comment: Did you try using  CSS classes or style?